# how to read JSON String to Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Below is my code where i fetch the data from database and pushed it into $response['subjects'].

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

            //$index['TimetableID'] = $row['TimetableID'];
            $index['CourseID'] = $row['CourseID'];
            $index['Course'] = $row['Course'];
            $index['CourseDescription'] = $row['CourseDescription'];
            $index['ClassName'] = $row['ClassName'];
            $index['CDay'] = $row['CDay'];

            $index['CTimeStart'] = $time_in_12_hour_format  = date("g:i a", strtotime($row['CTimeStart']));

            $index['CTimeEnd'] = $time_in_12_hour_format  = date("g:i a", strtotime($row['CTimeEnd']));

            $index['CourseGroup'] = $row['CourseGroup'];


            array_push($response['subjects'],$index);

        }
    }


echo json_encode($response);
```

Once i echo it display the data as below

```
{"subjects": 
[{"CourseID":"1","Course":"ACC418","CourseDescription":"FINANCIAL 
 ACCOUNTING","ClassName":"BK10","CDay":"MONDAY","CTimeStart":"8:00 
 am","CTimeEnd":"10:00 am","CourseGroup":"CS2453A"}]}
```

i want to fetch the whole information where CourseID is 1. but i don't know how to do it. i try json_decode($response,true) but it show error message

> json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string.

Comment: For your json string is not well formed.

Comment: what do you mean by not well formed?? @KrisRoofe

Comment: What's the value of `$response`?

Comment: i declared '$response' = array(). @KrisRoofe

Comment: `json_decode()` accept first parameter as string not array.

Comment: you already have an array `$response`, just access the information from it. look like you can access it using `$response['subjects'][0];`